# Validate population of generated classes against XSD

Tags: c#, xml, xsd

I've got an `XSD` which I've turned into classes using the VS `XSD.exe`

The code will populate these classes before getting to a stage when I then want to validate that they are "correctly" populated - for example, **if a field is mandatory in the XSD, but it is a string object in the generated class, will anything stop me from leaving it blank?** - if nothing stops me it will be invalid! (Something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29841041/xsd-exe-generated-class-doesnt-serialize-mandatory-elements-when-null-value) question)

I'm trying to avoid generating my `XML` and then reading it back in and validating the actual `XML` against the `XSD` if this is at all possible. I want to know that the population of the classes has been done wrong before I even attempt to generate the `XML`.

Any thoughts or examples would be great!

There are lots of articles about validating `XML` against an `XSD` but I can't find anything helpful about validating the population of the generated classes against an `XSD`. I don't know if this is possible!

Answer (score 0):

xsd.exe will add some extra boolean properties (for example: thisStringSpecified) which you can use for validating mandatory strings.

```
myClass.ThisStringSpecified = string.IsNullOrEmpty(ThisString);
```

You can test it afterwards by Serializing the object and use the XSD to validate it (if you want to be really sure).